# Bound for $\mathbb{P}[|X| \geq x]$ where $X$ is a standard normal random variable

Tags: probability, inequality

Let X be a standard Gaussian random variable. I have to prove that for every $x > 0$
$$
\frac{x}{1+x^2} e^{-x^2/2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathbb{P}[|X| \geq x] \leq \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$

Below my attempt
$$
\mathbb{P}[|X| \geq x] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[-x \leq X \leq x] = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-x^2/2} \, \text{d} x
$$
hence
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathbb{P}[|X| \geq x] = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \int_0^x e^{-x^2/2} \, \text{d} x.
$$
A first rough estimation is
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - 1 \leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathbb{P}[|X| \geq x] \leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$
Let's focus on
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathbb{P}[|X| \geq x] \leq \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
I tried to study the equation
$$
 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}
$$
in order to find the value $z$ such that the inequality would hold trivially, namely the values for which
$$
 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \leq \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
For the other values I thought that, given a shaper bound, I could study easily the inequality.
Anyway I can't find the exact value of the equation above and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more convenient to use

$$\mathbb{P}(|X| \geqslant x)= \mathbb{P}(X \geqslant x)+ \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant -x) = 2\mathbb{P}(X \geqslant x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\, dt$$

which implies that

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathbb{P}(|X| \geqslant x)= \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2} \, dt $$

For the upper bound we have

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\, dt = \frac{1}{x} \cdot x\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \leqslant \frac{1}{x} \int_x^\infty te^{-t^2/2}\, dt = -\frac{1}{x}\left.e^{-t^2/2}\right|_x^\infty = \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}\\ \implies \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathbb{P}(|X| \geqslant x) \leqslant \frac{1}{x} e^{-x^2/2}$$